# Simplify multiple is_a? calls on object

Tags: ruby

How to rewrite this line using an iterator?

```
actor.inspect if actor.is_a? Array || actor.is_a? Hash
```

My attempt that dosen't work:

```
actor.inspect if [Array, Hash].each { |c| actor.is_a? c }
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you want to match exact classes (and not descendants), you can use:

```
[Hash, Array].member? a.class
```

I think you should explain what exactly you need to achieve. Perhaps the only thing you need to check is if your object is an `Enumerable` or not, or even if it `respond_to?` some particular method.

Comment: This checks that `a.class == Hash` or `Array`, but will fail for subclasses of them...
+1 for `is_a?(Enumerable)` instead...

Comment: @Marc-AndréLafortune is correct, I just experienced this issue with subclasses. Lucky rspec caught it!

Answer (score 13):

You're looking for `Array#any?`

```
actor.inspect if [Array, Hash].any? { |c| actor.is_a? c }
```

`#each` usually just returns the enumerable.  `#any?`  ors together the result of the blocks.

Answer (score 2):

### Create an `is_any?` method.

If you are doing this often, it might be best to create an initializer (or any file that gets loaded in if you're not using Rails) that adds a new method called `is_any?` to `Object`.

#### Initializer

**`config/initializers/is_any.rb`**

```
class Object

  def is_any?( *klasses )              # Using the splat and flatten allows this to accept
    klasses.flatten.any? do |klass|    # both comma separated params as well as an Array.
      self.is_a?( klass )
    end
  end

end
```

#### Usage

```
actor.is_any? Array, Hash
```

or

```
actor.is_any? [ Array, Hash ]
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Use `.include?`

Instead of using `.is_a?` for class type, you can also put all the classes in an `Array` and then see if the object's class is included in that `Array`, for example:

```
[ Array, Hash ].include?( actor.class )
```

*NOTE: This will not check subtypes, like `is_a?` will.*